# How can I deploy a service provider and activity package together within eclipse

Tags: android

In Eclipse I want to deploy both a Service Provider package and a standard Activity-based package (which uses the Service Provider).  Can I bundle these together in Eclipse to make a single apk which gets deployed to the device?

thanks

anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, i have worked it out.  You simply add a package under the source folder and then add classes to this, remembering to update the manifest file with the extra 'provider' details.